# Avoid sticky header view when tableview scrolls with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview, snapkit

Currently when table content is scrolling, the `headerLabel` follows scroll and sticks to the top. How can I have avoid this behaviour with Auto Layout?

```
var tableView: UITableView!

let headerLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)

    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 34.0)
    label.textColor = .black
    label.textAlignment = .center

    return label
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let barHeight: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height

    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: barHeight, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height - barHeight))
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "tableCell")
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none

    view.addSubview(headerLabel)
    view.addSubview(tableView)

    headerLabel.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(view).offset(35)
        make.width.equalToSuperview()
    }

    tableView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.equalTo(headerLabel.snp.bottom)
        make.left.bottom.right.equalToSuperview()
    }
}
```

The `headerLabel` should scroll with `tableView` and should not look like sticky header.

Comment: Instead of adding the label separately to the view, you can add the label as a cell OR as a section header in a plain table view using the table view datasource methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your table view and your label are siblings inside your UIViewController's view, which means your label is not part of the table view so it won't scroll with it. You can add the label to a UIView, set it's constraints and then set the `tableHeaderView` property of the table view. Here's a sample code with some hardcoded values:

```
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.text = "some text"
    label.sizeToFit()

    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    headerView.addSubview(label)

    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

    headerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    headerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    label.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leftAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true

    tableView.tableHeaderView?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 12):

Change the Tableview Style from  Plain to Grouped. Your header will move with the table cell scroll.

[image]